# sleep(1) or sleepForTimeInterval 1 takes more than 1 second to wake

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Im facing a most peculiar bug that sleep(1) takes more than one second to wake, so I tried replacing sleep() with usleep() as well as [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0f], but issue is still there most of the time it works but in an average of 10 minutes run it is reproducible.
I have debugged by NSLogging before and after the sleep with a timestamp, also I'm attaching a screenshot with Wireshark. My objective is to get a continuous 1 sec poll

```
NSLog(@"4.ProcessHeartBeat: before sleepForTimeInterval check: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);

 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0f];

NSLog(@"5.ProcessHeartBeat: after sleepForTimeInterval check: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
```

the whole code runs on an infinite thread implemented using NSThread

[image]

Comment: According to the NSLog timestamps, the messages are 1.003 seconds apart.

Comment: And please don't add arbitrary tags. There is no Swift code in your question. Is it about iOS or macOS?

Comment: It is pretty normal for sleep calls to be a tiny little bit imprecise. The only peculiar thing in your log is that your formatted/printed date is somehow wrong for the selected lines - it doesn’t correspond to the actual logging time (the left part of log line).

Comment: Thread sleep only guarantees "at least" time percision

Comment: Did you try to save the start date and the end date to some variables and log both of them after the sleep? `NSLog` call is slow, it waits for the main thread to execute. So that's maybe the reason of 0.003 delay.

Something like that:

`NSDate* begin = [NSDate date];
[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval: 1.0f];
NSDate* end = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"4.ProcessHeartBeat: before sleepForTimeInterval check: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:begin]);
NSLog(@"5.ProcessHeartBeat: after sleepForTimeInterval check: %@", [formatter stringFromDate:end]);`

Answer (score 0):

In general, polling is bad.  Any way to not poll?

Sleeping threads is also bad;   should really be avoided.  Especially the main thread (no idea if that is the main thread or not)

Specifically, all the variants of sleep are not guaranteed to be time accurate for a variety of reasons.

You can try dispatch_after() or an NSTimer, but it is unlikely to be any more accurate.   It would, at least, not sleep() a thread.

Overall, your code should be written such that it processes stuff at approximately the right time and then uses the system clock to determine how much time actually elapsed.   Note that because of all kinds of power management and thermal mitigation tricks, the CPU speed, itself, could be variable.  So, things like # of clock cycles isn't meaningful.